# Freemarker pagination with Search parameter

Tags: url, search, pagination, freemarker, http-request-parameters

I have working pagination with Fremarker. Here is pager makros:

```
<#macro pager url page>
    <#if page.getTotalPages() gt 7>
        <#assign
        totalPages = page.getTotalPages()
        pageNumber = page.getNumber() + 1

        head = (pageNumber > 4)?then([1, -1], [1, 2, 3])
        tail = (pageNumber < totalPages - 3)?then([-1, totalPages], [totalPages - 2, totalPages - 1, totalPages])
        bodyBefore = (pageNumber > 4 && pageNumber < totalPages - 1)?then([pageNumber - 2, pageNumber - 1], [])
        bodyAfter = (pageNumber > 2 && pageNumber < totalPages - 3)?then([pageNumber + 1, pageNumber + 2], [])

        body = head + bodyBefore + (pageNumber > 3 && pageNumber < totalPages - 2)?then([pageNumber], []) + bodyAfter + tail
        >
    <#else>
        <#assign body = 1..page.getTotalPages()>
    </#if>
    <div class="container-fluid mt-3">
        <div class="row">
            <ul class="pagination col">
                <li class="page-item disabled">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">Pages</a>
                </li>
                <#list body as p>
                    <#if (p - 1) == page.getNumber()>
                        <li class="page-item active">
                            <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">${p}</a>
                        </li>
                    <#elseif p == -1>
                        <li class="page-item disabled">
                            <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">...</a>
                        </li>
                    <#else>
                        <li class="page-item">
                            <a class="page-link" href="${url}?page=${p - 1}&size=${page.getSize()}" tabindex="-1">${p}</a>
                        </li>
                    </#if>
                </#list>
            </ul>

            <ul class="pagination col justify-content-end">
                <li class="page-item disabled">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">Elements per page</a>
                </li>
                <#list [20, 40, 80, 120] as c>
                    <#if c == page.getSize()>
                        <li class="page-item active">
                            <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">${c}</a>
                        </li>
                    <#else>
                        <li class="page-item">
                            <a class="page-link" href="${url}?page=${page.getNumber()}&size=${c}" tabindex="-1">${c}</a>
                        </li>
                    </#if>
                </#list>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</#macro>
```

And pagination URL looks like:

> http://localhost:8080/main?page=1&size=10

There is search functionality for the main page:

```
<@c.page>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <form method="get" action="/main" class="form-inline">
                <input type="text" name="filter" class="form-control" value="${filter?ifExists}"
                       placeholder="Search by tag"/>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ml-2">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</@c.page>
```

if the search is entered, URL will look like:

> http://localhost:8080/main?filter=search-param

However, pagination doesn't work with URL which has entered search param (it is called filter actually).

Tried to add something like following to `pager.ftl`:

```
<#if '${url}'?contains("filter")>
    <a class="page-link" href="${url}&page=${p - 1}&size=${page.getSize()}" tabindex="-1">${p}</a>
<#else>
    <a class="page-link" href="${url}?page=${p - 1}&size=${page.getSize()}" tabindex="-1">${p}</a>
</#if>
```

The idea was check URL if filter param is set -> add pagination to it:

> http://localhost:8080/main?filter=search-param&page=1&size=10

If there is no search param, use the default one.

And it didn't work.

Here are full [Project Sources at GitHub](https://github.com/nazar-art/sweater).

Backend logic with Spring Boot and Spring Data work pretty well.

---

Tried solution by @ddekany. Here is the result:

```
<#else>
    <li class="page-item">    
        <a class="page-link"
           href="${url}${url?contains('?')?then('&', '?')}page=${p - 1}&size=${page.getSize()}"
           tabindex="-1">
            ${p}
        </a>
    </li>
</#if>
```

and the second part:

```
<#else>
    <li class="page-item">
        <a class="page-link"
           href="${url}${url?contains('?')?then('&', '?')}page=${page.getNumber()}&size=${c}"
           tabindex="-1">
            ${c}
        </a>
    </li>
</#if>
```

Here is when you enter the search:

[image]

However, when you press `2` page of a search you will be redirected to the main page (search is empty instead of going to #2 page of search results):

[image]

---

**SOLUTION:**

Correct setting the URL at controller:

```
Page<MessageDto> page = messageService.messageList(pageable, filter, user);

if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(filter)) {
    model.addAttribute("url", String.format("/main?filter=%s", filter));
} else {
    model.addAttribute("url", "/main");
}

model.addAttribute("page", page);
model.addAttribute("filter", filter);

return "main";
```

and change set URL at pager:

```
<li class="page-item">
    <#--<a class="page-link" href="${url}?page=${p - 1}&size=${page.getSize()}" tabindex="-1">${p}</a>-->
    <a class="page-link" href="${url}${url?contains('?')?then('&', '?')}page=${p - 1}&size=${page.getSize()}" tabindex="-1">
        ${p}
    </a>
</li>
```

and

```
<li class="page-item">
    <#--<a class="page-link" href="${url}?page=${page.getNumber()}&size=${c}" tabindex="-1">${c}</a>-->
    <a class="page-link" href="${url}${url?contains('?')?then('&', '?')}page=${page.getNumber()}&size=${c}" tabindex="-1">
        ${c}
    </a>
</li>
```

Commented lines are old code. Uncommented is exactly working.

***Question is how to configure Fremarker for such functionality?***

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"? Also, I would just look for '?' instead of 'filter'. (But most probably, I would avoid putting together urls in a template altogether.)

Comment: As a side note, `page.getNumber()`, and all these get stuff, can be written as `page.number`.

Comment: @ddekany I didn't do what I want to achieve -> when set and filter has value I want to cocat pagination like `&....`. If there is no filter param concat it like `?....`

Comment: Are you actually redirected, or simply that URL is what the #2 link points to? In which case, it seems that the `url` variable doesn't contain the `?filter=...` part. Not sure where the value of `url` is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check again, because that `#if` should work.

However, I would look for `?`, as it's more robust than looking for `filter`, as it works even if the parameter is later renamed.

Also, `<#if '${url}'?contains('...')>` can be just written as `<#if url?contains('...')>`.

Actually, you probably don't want to repeat that whole line, only to replace a single character, so just write

`href="${url}${url?contains('?')?then('&', '?')}page=...`.

(You can test out such things quickly on [Freemarker demo](https://try.freemarker.apache.org.))

Comment: Pagination is stopped to work after this update. Updated answer with code looking.

Comment: @catch23 Remove the `<#if url?contains('filter')>` tag and the corresponding `</#if>` tag. My point was that you don't need `#if`, instead you can use the other thing with the `?then`. Also, your chances of getting answers will be much higher if you tell what exactly happened, instead of "stopped working" and such.